# Draggable HTML <form> inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

While there are plenty of answers regarding draggable HTML elements using jQuery, I'd like for the user to be able to specifically **reorder items in a list and then have the ranking for each object (i.e. 1 for top, 3 for bottom) saved as a normal form `<input>`**.

I began tinkering with some Javascript and looking at [plenty of different resources](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=draggable%20form%20elements&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=a1c6f9eb6d5a9b1b&bpcl=40096503&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.eWU&biw=1386&bih=779) (including [this good one](http://tool-man.org/ToolManDHTML/sorting.html)). However, they only detail how to *move things around*, not how to store the actual positions to an `<input>` object. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
IDEALLY:
<input name="item-a-ranking" type="text">
-- the javascript then determines what text is "typed in" (i.e. 1, 2, or 3) for each.
```

Comment: [link](jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the JQueryUI project, widget Sortable : http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

There is a method called [serialize](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) to retrieve the element order.

**EDIT**

You could also use the `toArray` method to retrieve an array of your element. Then loop through your array to format in a specific format if you need.

**EDIT 2**

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/yg4n6/7/

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var dataItem = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize");
    alert(dataItem);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'save-sorting-position.php',
        data : dataItem,
        success: function(data) {                
            alert('Positions saved');
        }
    });
});
```

The idea is to call a php page to store the item position into your database.

Go through the `$_GET` (`$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`) array to retrieve your data :

save-sorting-position.php :

```
<?php 
    $arr = unserialize($_REQUEST["item"]); 
    foreach($arr as $index => $position)
    {
        //store the position here
    }
?>
```

Comment: I started to put together something, but then I realized I didn't really understand what you meant. How does one use serialize/toArray to input data to a form? I assume it'd be through `<input type="hidden">` objects, but I don't really know where to begin; could you give me a starting point?

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I've started working on something at http://jsfiddle.net/tehsockz/sccqR/ — however, the sortability seems to be missing. Do you know what I did wrong? How would that work? Sorry for the (quite) newbie-ish questions; PHP is still a bit of a mystery.